# RxJava - Map observable values into error

Tags: rx-java

I have an observable that emits one value and then completes. I want to transform this into an observable that either completes successfully or fails based on the value in emitted in the original observable.

I am able to accomplish this with `materialize`/`dematerialize` but it's verbose. Is there a better way to write this?

```
Observable<Car> car = loadCar();

Observable<Double> failsIfNoGas = car.materialize()
        .map(new Func1<Notification<Car>, Notification<Double>>() {
            @Override
            public Notification<Double> call(Notification<Car> notif) {
                if (notif.isOnNext()) {
                    Car car = notif.getValue();
                    if (car.gasLevel < 0.25) {
                        return Notification.createOnError(new Exception());
                    } else {
                        return Notification.createOnCompleted();
                    }
                } else if (notif.isOnCompleted()) {
                    return Notification.createOnCompleted();
                } else {
                    return Notification.createOnError(notif.getThrowable());
                }
            }
         })
         .dematerialize();

Observable<Double> takeEmployeeToLunchAndGetPrice = 
        Observable.concat(failsIfNoGas, driveEmployeeToLunch());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish the same thing just using `flatMap()` that returns `Observables` that call `onError` or `onCompleted`:

```
car.flatMap(c ->
  c.gasLevel < 0.25 ? Observable.error(new Exception()) : Observable.empty();
);
```

That said, I might reconsider your design of using `onError` for flow control because it makes streams difficult to use. It's a lot like using try-catch for flow.

Comment: For the original example, `car.flatMap( c -> c.gasLevel < 0.25 ? Observable.empty() : driveEmployeeToLunch() )` might be a better translation, without the side track into error handling.